# Importing vue template snippet results in [Object Promise]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, promise

I'm trying to dynamically include a template snippet from another file into my SFC template, but where I'd like the markup to appear I only get `[Object Promise]`. I understand this is because `import(…)` returns a Promise, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve it. I've tried simply putting it in the template and I've tried resolving it in a function (`import(…).then((t) => t)`). Doesn't make any difference. Minimal example follows.

`@/components/DynamicTemplateImport.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="(filename, idx) of templates"
      v-bind:key="idx"
    >
      {{ import(`@/templates/${filename}.vue`) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class DynamicTemplateImport extends Vue {
  templates = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
}
</script>
```

`@/templates/Foo.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <p>Foo</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <component v-for="(c, i) in comp" :is="getComponent(c)" :key="i" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      comp: ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getComponent(name) {
      return () => import(`./components/${name}.vue`);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create 3 component 'Foo', 'Bar' and 'Baz' then use `<component :is="myDynamicComponent"></component>` :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="myDynamicComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    myDynamicComponent() {
      if (// Foo wanted) {
        return () => import('@/components/Foo');
      } else if (// Bar wanted) {
        return () => import('@/components/Bar');
      } else if (// Baz wanted) {
        return () => import('@/components/Baz');
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Problem is I need all the components - note they're in a loop - and I specifically would like to avoid hardcoding all the sub-components into my SFC. (The `templates` variable is just a placeholder, my real component would be data-driven.)

Comment: @kthy You can do something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-water-xxww5). Actually I believe you can do even more shorter with just `<component :is='() => import(`@/templates/${filename}`)'/>` no need to create wrapper component but this doesn't work on codesandbox.